# Laravel Relaton Return null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two table

one is products another is offers

```
products
---------
id | offer_id

offers
---------
id | product_id
```

Now I want to get all offers against a product

In my product model I wrote

```
public function getOfferDetails()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Offer');
}
```

but it return null.

Comment: Well, are there any offers in the offers table tied to that product?

Comment: Incidentally, the `products` table typically shouldn't have an `offer_id` column.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get all `offers` that belong to a `product`, right? Have you tried this:

```
public function getOfferDetails()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Offer');
}
```

In your `Product` model?

Answer (score 0):

Need to define how your relationships are. Based on what you have

A Product can have 0 - many offers and an Offer belongs to 1 Product.

You will need some foreign key to match the models. OTB Laravel will attempt to use the method name appended with _id as the foreign key. Since your method name is different, you need to pass the foreign key as the second parameter in your relationship method.

Products Model should have

```
public function getOfferDetails()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Offer', 'product_id');
}
```

Offer Model should have

```
public function getProduct()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'product_id');
}
```

[Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) that might help out as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for I think:

```
public function getOfferDetails()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Offer', 'id', 'offer_id');
    // as ceejayoz mentioned in comments, Laravel should be able to detect this themselves. The below would work the exact same as above
    // return $this->hasMany('App\Offer', 'id', 'offer_id')
}

$product->getOfferDetails()->get();
```

Comment: If tables and fields are named per the Laravel docs (which they appear to be) the extra params are unnecessary.